# Web Service in google apps script to receive files

Tags: google-apps-script

As we all know that we can write simple web services using google apps script and handle the GET request in `doGet(e)`. The e contains the parameters. 
Similarly doPost(e) would handle the POST request and e would contain the parameters.

I was wondering how would I be able to send a file(without google forms or input type=file) from a custom client(e.g. android app) and process it in doGet. I could not find any samples whatsoever(without using input type=file) anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML form can call this server side method using google.script.run and it should save the file on to Google Drive.

```
function save(form) {

  try {

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

From: [Upload Files to Google Drive with Apps Script](http://ctrlq.org/code/19747-google-forms-upload-files)

Comment: Finally, the answer from the master himself! I love the articles of your blog ctrlq. In my case, I am not using a html form, so I can not use any javascript function like google.script.run. I have to do http POST from a custom client like an android app to save the file.

Comment: its still usable. just put that code in doGet use contentService to return status.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like form.myFile is not a blob type when passed to doPost(e) method. Instead it is a string type.

My question: does Google script engine handle doGet and doPost differently in preparing parameter e passing to the two methods?

Server side:

```
function doPost(e) {

    var blob = e.parameter.myFile;
    // the variable blob is NOT a Blob type, but a string type

    // Other code ...
}
```

At client side a binary file is "posted" from a .NET client, and verified with my own upload server, and the POST works correctly.